# Members cannot get member list in a muc room

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework, multiuserchat

I'm using IOS XMPPFramework for our chat application and I'm creating the group and adding the selected member with the below code, and receipants succesfully joins the group.
And if I query the member list of that group admins succesfully retrieve the group's members but members cannot get the same list and instead they are receiving the below error:

```
<iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="250034370263@conference.chat.meeapps.com.tr" to="16503312600@chat.meeapps.com.tr/15323458207749806891286" id="FF691FF5-D12B-4BAA-AB19-84E7A2B945D4" type="error"><query xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#admin"><item affiliation="member"/></query><error code="403" type="auth"><forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Administrator privileges required</text></error></iq>
```

You can find the create and invite codes below:

```
- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom*)sender didFetchMembersList:(NSArray *)items
{
    CLS_LOG(@"Received MemberList: %@",items);
    if (sender.inviteMemberList) {
        if ([sender.inviteMemberList count]) {

            for (NSString *user in sender.inviteMemberList) {
                [sender inviteUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:user] withMessage:nil];
            }


            CLS_LOG(@"Adding Members To Group %@",sender.inviteMemberList);
            XMPPIQ *addMemberIQ = [XMPPIQ addMembersToGroup:sender.inviteMemberList withElementId:[self generateMessageID] andNick:sender.nickName andGroupJid:[sender.roomJID bare]];
            CLS_LOG(@"Sending IQ To Add Member: %@",addMemberIQ);
            [xmppStream sendElement:addMemberIQ];
            sender.inviteMemberList = nil;
        }
    }


}

+ (nonnull instancetype) addMembersToGroup:(NSArray *)memberList withElementId:(NSString*)elementId andNick:(NSString*)nick andGroupJid:(NSString*)groupJid
{
    NSXMLElement *queryElement = [self elementWithName:@"query" xmlns:XMPPMUCAdminNamespace];

    for (NSString *member in memberList) {
        NSXMLElement *itemElement = [self elementWithName:@"item"];
        [itemElement addAttributeWithName:@"affiliation" stringValue:@"member"];
        [itemElement addAttributeWithName:@"jid" stringValue:member];

        [queryElement addChild:itemElement];
    }


    return [self iqWithType:@"set" to:[XMPPJID jidWithString:groupJid] elementID:elementId child:queryElement];
}
```

**[EDIT]**
You can also find my room config in the below xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<x xmlns="jabber:x:data" type="form">
   <title>Configuration of room 259297300263@conference.chat.meeapps.com.tr</title>
   <field type="hidden" var="FORM_TYPE">
      <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#roomconfig</value>
   </field>
   <field type="text-single" label="Room title" var="muc#roomconfig_roomname">
      <value>osmannn</value>
   </field>
   <field type="text-single" label="Room description" var="muc#roomconfig_roomdesc">
      <value />
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Make room persistent" var="muc#roomconfig_persistentroom">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Make room public searchable" var="muc#roomconfig_publicroom">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Make participants list public" var="public_list">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Make room password protected" var="muc#roomconfig_passwordprotectedroom">
      <value>0</value>
   </field>
   <field type="text-private" label="Password" var="muc#roomconfig_roomsecret">
      <value />
   </field>
   <field type="list-single" label="Maximum Number of Occupants" var="muc#roomconfig_maxusers">
      <value>200</value>
      <option label="5">
         <value>5</value>
      </option>
      <option label="10">
         <value>10</value>
      </option>
      <option label="20">
         <value>20</value>
      </option>
      <option label="30">
         <value>30</value>
      </option>
      <option label="50">
         <value>50</value>
      </option>
      <option label="100">
         <value>100</value>
      </option>
      <option label="200">
         <value>200</value>
      </option>
   </field>
   <field type="list-single" label="Present real Jabber IDs to" var="muc#roomconfig_whois">
      <value>anyone</value>
      <option label="moderators only">
         <value>moderators</value>
      </option>
      <option label="anyone">
         <value>anyone</value>
      </option>
   </field>
   <field type="list-multi" label="Roles for which Presence is Broadcasted" var="muc#roomconfig_presencebroadcast">
      <value>moderator</value>
      <value>participant</value>
      <value>visitor</value>
      <option label="Moderator">
         <value>moderator</value>
      </option>
      <option label="Participant">
         <value>participant</value>
      </option>
      <option label="Visitor">
         <value>visitor</value>
      </option>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Make room members-only" var="muc#roomconfig_membersonly">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Make room moderated" var="muc#roomconfig_moderatedroom">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Default users as participants" var="members_by_default">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Allow users to change the subject" var="muc#roomconfig_changesubject">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Allow users to send private messages" var="allow_private_messages">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="list-single" label="Allow visitors to send private messages to" var="allow_private_messages_from_visitors">
      <value>anyone</value>
      <option label="nobody">
         <value>nobody</value>
      </option>
      <option label="moderators only">
         <value>moderators</value>
      </option>
      <option label="anyone">
         <value>anyone</value>
      </option>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Allow users to query other users" var="allow_query_users">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Allow users to send invites" var="muc#roomconfig_allowinvites">
      <value>0</value>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Allow visitors to send status text in presence updates" var="muc#roomconfig_allowvisitorstatus">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Allow visitors to change nickname" var="muc#roomconfig_allowvisitornickchange">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Allow visitors to send voice requests" var="muc#roomconfig_allowvoicerequests">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="boolean" label="Allow subscription" var="muc#roomconfig_allow_subscription">
      <value>1</value>
   </field>
   <field type="text-single" label="Minimum interval between voice requests (in seconds)" var="muc#roomconfig_voicerequestmininterval">
      <value>1800</value>
   </field>
   <field type="jid-multi" label="Exclude Jabber IDs from CAPTCHA challenge" var="muc#roomconfig_captcha_whitelist" />
</x>
```

Can you help me with that problem?

**[EDIT 2:]**
I've changed my code like in the below code. And I also made the configuration same with you, But still the same result. Am I missing something in server side ?

```
- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom *)sender didFetchConfigurationForm:(NSXMLElement *)configForm{

        NSXMLElement *newConfig = [configForm copy];
        NSArray* fields = [newConfig elementsForName:@"field"];
        for (NSXMLElement *field in fields) {
            NSString *var = [field attributeStringValueForName:@"var"];

            if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_persistentroom"]) {
                [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
                [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];

            }else if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_roomname"]){
                [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
                [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:sender.groupName]];

            }
            else if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_publicroom"]){
                [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
                [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"0"]];
            }
            else if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_whois"]) {
                [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
                [field insertChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"anyone"] atIndex:0];
            }
            else if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_allow_subscription"]) {
                [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
                [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];
            }
            else if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_membersonly"]){
              [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
              [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];
            }
            else if ([var isEqualToString:@"public_list"]){
                [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
                [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];
            }
            else if ([var isEqualToString:@"muc#roomconfig_allowinvites"]){
                [field removeChildAtIndex:0];
                [field addChild:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"value" stringValue:@"1"]];
            }
        }
        CLS_LOG(@"Sending Configuration: %@",newConfig);
        [sender configureRoomUsingOptions:newConfig];


        if (sender.inviteMemberList) {
            CLS_LOG(@"Adding Members To Group %@",sender.inviteMemberList);
            XMPPIQ *addMemberIQ = [XMPPIQ addMembersToGroup:sender.inviteMemberList withElementId:[self generateMessageID] andNick:sender.nickName andGroupJid:[sender.roomJID bare]];
            CLS_LOG(@"Sending IQ To Add Member: %@",addMemberIQ);
            [xmppStream sendElement:addMemberIQ];
            [sender fetchMembersList];

        }

}

- (void)xmppRoom:(XMPPRoom*)sender didFetchMembersList:(NSArray *)items{

    CLS_LOG(@"Fetched Members: %@",items);

    if (sender.inviteMemberList) {
        if ([sender.inviteMemberList count]) {

            for (NSString *user in sender.inviteMemberList) {
                [sender inviteUser:[XMPPJID jidWithString:user] withMessage:nil];
            }


            sender.inviteMemberList = nil;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the `muc#roomconfig_whois` to `anyone` when configuring the room.

```
 <field
          label='Who May Discover Real JIDs?'
          type='list-single'
          var='muc#roomconfig_whois'>
        <option label='Moderators Only'>
          <value>moderators</value>
        </option>
        <option label='Anyone'>
          <value>anyone</value>
        </option>
  </field>
```

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#roomconfig

[Edited 2]:

I guess I kinna figure out what was wrong. From your code, you invited users first, then add them to members.

Could you try reverse the flow.  Add all to members first, and then invite.  Otherwise when a user gets the invitation, the members might not be set on Xmpp Server yet.

Here is what I did：

- Join a room, (if the room is not existing, server will create it).
- In xmppRoomDidCreate, fetch config form.
- Send the config form, and **Add All Members** right after.
- In didConfigure, send invitations.

The flow is kind of slow, I suggest you add the settings as default settings in mod_muc.  Just make sure add members before send invitation.

[Edited]:

Here is my form when configuring the room:

```
<x xmlns=\"jabber:x:data\" type=\"form\">
      <title>Configuration of room 1479231695@conference.192.168.100.226</title>
      <field type=\"hidden\" var=\"FORM_TYPE\">
        <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#roomconfig</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"text-single\" label=\"Room title\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_roomname\">
        <value></value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"text-single\" label=\"Room description\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_roomdesc\">
        <value></value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Make room persistent\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_persistentroom\">
        <value>1</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Make room public searchable\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_publicroom\">
        <value>0</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Make participants list public\" var=\"public_list\">
        <value>0</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Make room password protected\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_passwordprotectedroom\">
        <value>0</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"text-private\" label=\"Password\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_roomsecret\">
        <value></value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"list-single\" label=\"Maximum Number of Occupants\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_maxusers\">
        <value>200</value>
        <option label=\"5\">
          <value>5</value>
        </option>
        <option label=\"10\">
          <value>10</value>
        </option>
        <option label=\"20\">
          <value>20</value>
        </option>
        <option label=\"30\">
          <value>30</value>
        </option>
        <option label=\"50\">
          <value>50</value>
        </option>
        <option label=\"100\">
          <value>100</value>
        </option>
        <option label=\"200\">
          <value>200</value>
        </option>
      </field>
      <field type=\"list-single\" label=\"Present real Jabber IDs to\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_whois\">
        <option label=\"moderators only\">
          <value>moderators</value>
        </option>
        <option label=\"anyone\">
          <value>anyone</value>
        </option>
        <value>anyone</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"list-multi\" label=\"Roles for which Presence is Broadcasted\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_presencebroadcast\">
        <value>moderator</value>
        <value>participant</value>
        <value>visitor</value>
        <option label=\"Moderator\">
          <value>moderator</value>
        </option>
        <option label=\"Participant\">
          <value>participant</value>
        </option>
        <option label=\"Visitor\">
          <value>visitor</value>
        </option>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Make room members-only\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_membersonly\">
        <value>1</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Make room moderated\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_moderatedroom\">
        <value>0</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Default users as participants\" var=\"members_by_default\">
        <value>1</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Allow users to change the subject\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_changesubject\">
        <value>1</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Allow users to send private messages\" var=\"allow_private_messages\">
        <value>1</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"list-single\" label=\"Allow visitors to send private messages to\" var=\"allow_private_messages_from_visitors\">
        <value>anyone</value>
        <option label=\"nobody\">
          <value>nobody</value>
        </option>
        <option label=\"moderators only\">
          <value>moderators</value>
        </option>
        <option label=\"anyone\">
          <value>anyone</value>
        </option>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Allow users to query other users\" var=\"allow_query_users\">
        <value>1</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Allow users to send invites\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_allowinvites\">
        <value>1</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Allow visitors to send status text in presence updates\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_allowvisitorstatus\">
        <value>1</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Allow visitors to change nickname\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_allowvisitornickchange\">
        <value>1</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"boolean\" label=\"Allow visitors to send voice requests\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_allowvoicerequests\">
        <value>1</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"text-single\" label=\"Minimum interval between voice requests (in seconds)\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_voicerequestmininterval\">
        <value>1800</value>
      </field>
      <field type=\"jid-multi\" label=\"Exclude Jabber IDs from CAPTCHA challenge\" var=\"muc#roomconfig_captcha_whitelist\"></field>
    </x>
```

As you can see, there is some differences on the items:

- muc#roomconfig_publicroom
- public_list
- muc#roomconfig_moderatedroom
- muc#roomconfig_allowinvites

I tried set the "muc#roomconfig_moderatedroom" to 1, still all members can get the members list. Not sure what happened on your side.

Comment: I've changed that  to anyone but the result is the same. You can see my config xml on the edited page

Comment: really weird, maybe you zip all your related code, from createRoom to InviteUser, and your serve config file,  and share it to me, I will try to figure out.  Never get your problem.

Comment: you can find the related code part in the below link:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3eSt3_PT8YXT1FReGxhU295anc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: sorry there was a mistake in the file. Latest file in this link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3eSt3_PT8YXSWF1aFU1aGJvQjQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't see the code where/when you call `fetchMemerList` for the invitedUsers.  I am expecting you handle "xmppMUC:roomJid:didreceiveInvitation" and call fetchMemberList inside.

Comment: You can find the latest code in below link:   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3eSt3_PT8YXbWpOWlJiTnBNN2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Where is the code that, invitedUser call fetchMembersList?

Comment: this is the code that inviteduser call fetchMemberList:
-(void)groupChatFetchMembersListWithGroupChatUserName:(NSString *)gChatUserName{
    XMPPRoom *room = [activatedGroupChats objectForKey:gChatUserName];
    [room fetchMembersList];
}

Comment: Come on, try to give me the full related code, I don't see this in your shared doc. otherwise can't help.

Comment: this is the final link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3eSt3_PT8YXd3dJNk5jTkZBaVU/view?usp=sharing
and this is the category that I created for XMPPRoom (Sending this just for info): 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3eSt3_PT8YXT1JBZEhyMWpqbUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: When/where `groupChatFetchMembersListWithGroupChatUserName` get called?

Comment: When the user presses a button on our application to see the members of the group (Like whatsapp)

Comment: I found the latest problem, its because xmppframework pod file is corrupted, I regenerated it and the problem solved, ofcourse with making the implementation that you suggested. Now I have one more problem left. When I fetch the member list , I also fetch the moderatorsList in order to show who is admin of the group,  server returns member list succesfully but doesnt return the moderator list and give the result of  `<error code="403" type="auth"><forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">Moderator privileges required</text></error></iq>`

Comment: For this, I forked the source and add a fetchOwnersList merged, similar to fetchMembersList, just replace 'member' with 'owner'.

Answer (score 1):

Let me add my working code in swift, you can check if there is any difference.  Sorry couldn't help more.

```
    func onButtonClicked(_ button: UIButton) {

        let roomJIDStr = theRoomJidStr // get the roomJid
        self.xmppRoom = joinRoom(with: roomJIDStr, delegate: self)
    }

    func joinRoom(with jidString: String, delegate: XMPPRoomDelegate) -> XMPPRoom {

        let roomJID = XMPPJID(string: jidString)
        let roomStorage = XMPPRoomCoreDataStorage.sharedInstance()

        let room = XMPPRoom(roomStorage: roomStorage, jid: roomJID, dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)!

        room.activate(xmppStream)

        room.addDelegate(delegate, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)

        room.join(usingNickname: xmppStream.myJID.user, history: nil)

        return room
    }

    public func xmppRoomDidCreate(_ sender: XMPPRoom!) {
        print("xmppRoomDidCreate")

        // Accept default settings
        let config = DDXMLElement(name: "x", xmlns: "jabber:x:data")
        sender.configureRoom(usingOptions: config)

        // Add members
        let query = DDXMLElement(name: "query", xmlns: XMPPMUCAdminNamespace)
        if let contacts = selectedContacts {

            for c in contacts {

                let item = DDXMLElement(name: "item")
                item.addAttribute(withName: "affiliation", stringValue: "member")
                item.addAttribute(withName: "jid", stringValue: c.xmppAccount!)

                query?.addChild(item)
            }
        }

        let id = XMPPStream.generateUUID()
        let to = sender.roomJID
        let iq = XMPPIQ(type: "set", to: to, elementID: id, child: query)

        chatManager.xmppStream.send(iq)
    }
```

Preconditions:

- I set some settings as mod_muc default options, so don't need to configure the room.

  `mod_muc:
      ## host: "conference.@HOST@"
      access:
        - allow
      access_admin:
        - allow: admin
      access_create: muc_create
      access_persistent: muc_create
      history_size: 0
      default_room_options:
          allow_user_invites: true
          anonymous: false
          members_by_default: true
          members_only: true
          moderated: false
          persistent: true
          public: false
          public_list: false`
- There is no Invite in my code, I add them directly into member list. And use [ejabberd_mod_offline_post](https://github.com/diamondbybold/ejabberd_mod_offline_post) for Push Notification.  When owner sends the first message, all other members will get the push and start fetching the member list.

Comment: What happens if the owner doesnt send any message and just create the room?
In that case the receipants dont aware of the group created right?

Comment: In my app, the room is created only if user sends the first msg.  But you are right, it depends on app's behavior .

Comment: @tolgatanriverdi - would you mind sharing please what was the pod issue? I have the same problem (though am not using pods but directly integrating the code), but still might help as to what is happening... Thanks much.