# Get MUC Room list which a user already participated

Tags: objective-c, xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

I'm using IOS XMPPFramework as our client infrastructure and we are using ejabberd as our XMPP Server.
However when users deleted their application its impossible to retrieve the already registered rooms.
Is something like that possible in XMPP (similar to whatsapp)

Thanks

Comment: See you again.  BTW, there is a question might need your help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40637958/fetching-ejabberd-muc-members-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Configure the room as Persistent, Member-Only.
2. Add the user into member list.
3. [Discover room](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#disco-rooms).

   ```
   xmppStream = XMPPStream()        
   xmppStream!.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)

   // MUC
   muc = XMPPMUC(dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
   muc?.activate(xmppStream)
   muc?.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)

   muc?.discoverRooms(forServiceNamed: XmppMUCServer)
   ```

Comment: But this doesnt give me the list of not joined rooms. It only returns the joined rooms however when I remove my application all list of group chats are removed too so I need to get the all groups which I already became a member

Comment: Well this is a custom requirement, not covered in XMPP, like in simple words you can store the list of user's rooms on your server and then when user is performing login on same device or on a new device, you retrieve the rooms from your backend server and then join those rooms.

Comment: @tolgatanriverdi, have you try already? I am doing as I said and it works fine on my side.  Delete the app, reinstall, launch.  I will get all rooms that I am a member of, when discoverRooms.

Comment: Nice solution. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The way to implement this would be to store Bookmarks on the server, which would be a list of all the rooms you are interested in. As bookmarks are stored on the server, you can still retrieve them when you reinstall the app.

The XMPP extension defining bookmarks is [XEP-0048](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0048.html).